# What's the proper way to handle an RAII member variable?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor, raii

I'm new to C++ and don't yet fully understand the RAII pattern. I'm writing a class which uses an sqlite database via [SQLiteC++](https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp). Here is some sample code that uses the database that works:

```
void test() {
    SQLite::Database db(TestDbPath(), SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);

    db.exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test");
    db.exec("CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, foobar TEXT)");
}
```

What I want to do is use an `SQLite::Database` from a class. Something like this would work:

```
class DBUser
{
private:
    SQLite::Database *db;

public:
    explicit DBUser(std::string &path) {
        db = new SQLite::Database(path, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);
    }
    ~DBUser() {
        delete db;
    }

    void test() {
        db->exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test");
        db->exec("CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, foobar TEXT)");
    }
}
```

Is that the best way, though? Is there a more idiomatic/elegant way to accomplish this without a pointer?

Comment: A simple data member?

Comment: Use `std::shared_ptr` if you have it, or `boost::shared_ptr` from the Boost library if you don't.

Comment: It might be appropriate in this case to use a `std::unique_ptr`. I don't think you can just share these pointers, considering the semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have an object as a member:

```
class DBUser
{
private:
    SQLite::Database db;

public:
    explicit DBUser(std::string &path) :
        db (path, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE) 
    {

    }
    void test() {
        db.exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test");
        db.exec("CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, foobar TEXT)");
    }
}
```

Comment: The clue was in the title: RAII almost always means use an object rather than a pointer.

Comment: Ah I see, I just wasn't sure how to initialize it... is this equivalent to `){ db = SQLite::Database db(path, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE); }`? If so what are the copy semantics exactly?